# Give an example to show that G must be assumed to be connected in identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This question is one question of the book Functions of one complex variable I (John B. Conway), Cap.4, Section 3.

The theorem. Let $G$ be a connected open set and let $f:G\rightarrow C$ be an analytic function. Then the following are equivalent statements:

(a) $f\equiv 0$;

(b) there is a point $a$ in $G$ such that $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for each $n\ge0$$

(c)$\{z\in G; f(z)=0\}$ has a limit point in $G$.

I could not think of any interesting feature to this problem.

Comment: take two disjoint connected set on each of which f is constant

Comment: It is possible to explain more clearly?

Comment: on each component f is constant so derivative is zero,but on each component f can have different constant value.So f is not necessarily 0 although its all derivatives are 0